# Multiple image uploads with paperclip/active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin, image-uploading

Hi I want to be able to upload multiple pictures for a `product` instead of just one as a can now through the code below.

I'm not sure how to manage my client request since I'm rather unexperienced working with `active admin` and `paperclip`

I have googled around and checked out various posts on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a solution yet. Any suggestions or help would be great....

This is the `product` model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :label

  has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]


    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_eu, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true


   has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
   validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/


   def self.search(query)

   where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%") 
  end
end
```

and this is the `app/admin/product.rb`

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Product do


  permit_params :title, :slug, :description, :stock_quantity, :image, :price_usd, :price_eu, :category_id, :label_id

  index do
      column :title
      column :slug
      column :category
      column :label
      column :created_at
      column :stock_quantity

      column :price_eu, :sortable => :price_eu do |product|
        number_to_currency(product.price_eu, :unit => " € " , :precision => 0) 
      end
      column :price_euro, :sortable => :price_usd do |product|
        number_to_currency(product.price_usd, :unit => " $ " , :precision => 0)
      end

      actions   

  end

form do |f|
        f.inputs do
        f.input :title
        f.input :slug
        f.input :description, as: :ckeditor, input_html: { ckeditor: { toolbar: 'Full' } }
        f.input :stock_quantity
        f.input :image
        f.input :price_usd
        f.input :price_eu
        f.input :category
        f.input :label
        end
        actions 
      end

end
```

And here is the `products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def show
  @meta_title = "Samoli #{@product.title}"
  @meta_description = @product.description

  end

def search

@product = Product.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC")
@categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @product.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct


end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price_usd, :price_eu, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug)
end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using something like jQuery file upload to handle the file uploads for you.

That way your controller still only handles one file upload at a time, though you can upload many files at a time as each upload is handled separately via an Ajax call.

I have tried other alternatives, but trying to post more than one file to a server at a time, you quickly run into server timeout issues (especially on heroku).

Here is a gem you can wire into ActiveAdmin

https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

Let me know if you need more help on the implementation.

UPDATE: (please see comments for context)

Here is some example code illustrating how to implement the code in active admin. I know it looks like a lot of code but just work through it step by step and you will see its pretty simple.

Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos
end
```

Photo model:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionView::Helpers

  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { large: "500x500>",thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

  def thumb
    link_to(image_tag(image.url(:thumb)), thumb_url)
  end

  private

  def thumb_url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.admin_product_photo_path(product, self)
  end
end
```

Then in active admin do the following.

ActiveAdmin Product:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  permit_params :title

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
    end
    f.actions
   end

  index do
    column :title
    column :images do |product|
      product.photos.map do |photo|
        link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:thumb)), [:admin, photo.product, photo]
      end.join.html_safe
    end
    actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table
    panel "Images" do
      div class: "js-product_photos" do
        product.photos.map do |photo|
          link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:thumb)), [:admin, photo.product, photo]
        end.join.html_safe
      end
      div do
        semantic_form_for [:admin, resource, Photo.new], multipart: true do |f|
          f.inputs do
            f.input :image, as: :file,
                            input_html: {
                              class: 'js-photo_upload',
                              type: "file",
                              name: "photo[image]",
                              multiple: true
                            }
          end
         end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note the html options defined in the form. That is where jQuery upload derives a lot of its options. the form url is also important.

I could have added the form anywhere, but I think it works well on the product show page.

ActiveAdmin Photo:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
  belongs_to :product
  permit_params :image

  controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
        format.json { render :json => {thumb: resource.thumb} }
      end
    end
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :product
      row :image do |product|
        image_tag product.image.url(:large)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and finally in the `active_admin.js.coffee`

```
#= require active_admin/base
#= require jquery-fileupload/basic

$ ->
  $('.js-photo_upload').fileupload dataType: 'json', done: (e, data) ->
    $('.js-product_photos').append data.result.thumb
```

And that's it! The files should upload via an AJAX call as soon as you select them. Once uploaded an image tag will be appended to the list of images. You can select more than one image at a time

This really just scratches the surface of what the basic jQuery file uploader can do - read more about it here. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Just for reference the app I built is a rails 5 app, here are the gems that were important for this example:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 5.0.0"
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"
```

UPDATE: Based on a further question

Now that you are able to upload images, you can display them on for example the product show page (`show.html.erb`):

```
<h1><%= @product.title %></h1>
<% @product.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag(photo.image.url(:large) %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great! thank you, I'll check it out later tonight, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @veldtmana, I added the gem to the `gemfile` but I'm not sure how to integrate it with `active admin` or at least I can't find good enough directions how to do that. Could you perhaps guide me with the implementation. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Slowboy, sure I'll quickly put something together for you

Comment: Thank you so much @veldtmana it would be great, I've been kind a stuck in this for the whole day

Comment: @Slowboy here is an example implementation - please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi @veldtmana Thank you very much, this is partly working for me, the admin part is working and I can upload images there. But I can´t see the images in the show.html.erb.... could you perhaps copy/paste your show.html.erb so I can see how you are doing this?

Comment: Hi @Slowboy I haven't done anything outside of ActiveAdmin, but the show page should be very simple. I'll add a code snippet to the Post

Comment: Hi @veldtmana, this is basically how I did it, I'm still getting this error `undefined method 'title' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8ca2189828>` and same goes for `photo`.... I'm not really getting why.... am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127404/discussion-between-veldtmana-and-slowboy).